# regarding to download multiple image for multiple urls in the background to my android app

Tags: android

how to download multiple images from multiple URLS  and when all images got downloaded to my sdcard, the images has to be upadted to list view items. please tell me in what way we can do it

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [Android Universal Image Loader by Nostra](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). This will help you download images from the internet easily rather than implementing it on your own. You can download the library(.jar) and import it to your project or using Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.nostra13.universalimageloader</groupId>
<artifactId>universal-image-loader</artifactId>
<version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

You can also follow [this tutorial](http://sunil-android.blogspot.com/2013/09/lazy-loading-image-download-from.html) to know how to use it with listview.

Answer (score 0):

check [this](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) and [this](http://androidexample.com/Download_Images_From_Web_And_Lazy_Load_In_ListView_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=112&aaid=134). you can also use [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).